# Is there anyway to get one client_id and client_secret for all the sites of the companies sharepoint?

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365

I am trying to get the excel content from the SharePoint site using client_id and client_secret. But I want to read the excel content from more than 100 sites under companies' SharePoint. Do I need to create them for all the sites separately or Is there any way to get the universal client_id and client_secret for all the sites of our company?

I can get credentials for one site, but it will be difficult task to get them for all the other sites of a company. I would like to read the excel file from all the differnt sharepoints, modify them, and save them to the database using python.

Comment: By client_id and client_secret you mean that you used the SharePoint App-only context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Sharepoint Online tenant, you could utilize the Azure-App Only context in order to have a client have access to the entire SharePoint Tenant.

Basically, you would have to [create an app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) with the below setting:
[image]

Next you would have to use a Python wrapper library to create a Client Context.
[This library](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client) seems to make a good fit.

Using the library you could create a ClientContex with the certificate credentials flow, found [here](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/connect_with_client_certificate.py) :

```
def create_client_with_scopes():
    cert_credentials = {
        'tenant': test_tenant,
        'client_id': '51d03106-4726-442c-86db-70b32fa7547f',
        'thumbprint': "78CA7402E8A2508A9772CB1B2E085945147D8050",
        'cert_path': '{0}/selfsigncert.pem'.format(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
        'scopes': ['{0}/.default'.format(test_site_url)]
    }

    return ClientContext(test_team_site_url).with_client_certificate(**cert_credentials)
```

### Notes

1. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread#can-i-use-other-means-besides-certificates-for-realizing-app-only-access-for-my-azure-ad-app) carefully and use the certificate authentication.